# How to use TextInputLayout as Button

Tags: android

I have a TextInputLayout with AppCompatEditText Like This

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rv_from_date_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edt_from_date_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_from_date_picker"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabelDark"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_from_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="From Date"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_from_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/date_range" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[ScreehShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVVIz.jpg)

On click of the AppCompatEditText i need to display an date picker. But i don't want the keyboard to popup.

I tried the following:

```
1. edt_from_date.setEnabled(false);
2. edt_from_date.setKeyListener(null);
3. rv_from_date_holder.setOnclickListener()//Also didn't worked
```

If I disable i am not able to popup the datepicker.
If i setKeyListener as null then I need to tap twice to get the date picker.

Answer (score 3):

You should add

> android:focusable="false"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_from_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="From Date"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

And inside activity/fragment set

> onClickListener

Comment: then which view i need to listen edt_from_date?

Answer (score 0):

**try this it will sure help you**

```
     // disable keyboard on editext on touch listener
   editText.setOnTouchListener(otl);

private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true; // the listener has consumed the event
    }
 };
```

**// open date picker here**

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open your date picker here
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will not stop the keyboard from popping up

Answer (score 0):

Rather than you do set enable the edit text to false like this `edt_from_date.setEnabled(false);` you can disabled the editable of the edit text like this `edt_from_date.setEditable(false);` then you still can `setOnClickListener()` without show the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:hint="Expiry Date"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**android:focusable="false"** is an attribute you need to add if you dont want keyboard to open.

Now to show date picker on click of it use below code :

```
your_edit_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
```

and finally code this to get Date

```
myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

         date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

        };
```

Hope,This will help you. :-)